# Getting all users specific info from active directory using script

Tags: active-directory

I need to acquire following information from the Windows 2008 Active Directory Domain Controller Server.

```
a) User name    
b) User ID  / O.U  
c) User Status (Disabled/Enabled)    
d) User Creation Date    
e) User Deletion Date    
f) User Last Login Date
```

I can get the user list by following command

```
dsquery user -limit 0 | dsget user -dn -disabled -display -email -dept -title
```

How can I get other information as well in single window or text file?

Comment: Never mind, I got it using following command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to acquire my customized result. I mostly use my **Ubuntu** box to manage my **Active Directory**. Following is full command from Linux terminal to acquire active directory user details for required query.

```
winexe -U DOMAIN/ADMIN%"PASSWORD" //10.0.0.0 'powershell.exe -command "import-module activedirectory; Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | select Name,UserPrincipalName,Enabled,LockedOut,Created,LastLogonDate"' > /tmp/ad-users-details.txt
```

I used semicolon to execute two commands in single line, it was required to import **AD modules** first

I then tag it with webmin base modules, and all Ok now for support staff as well.

:)

Regard's

Jz